# Get classname, Hide ID with each class, filtering script

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, hide, each

I'm trying to filter some elements when we click on them.

ID = unique grid ID
class = grid not compatible with the current grid id.

```
<ul class="list-grids">
<li id="grille1" class="grille4 grille5 "></li>
<li id="grille2" class="grille4 grille5 "></li>
<li id="grille3" class="grille5 "></li>
<li id="grille4" class="grille1 grille2 "></li>
<li id="grille5" class="grille1 grille2 grille3 "></li>
</ul>
```

In this example, ID="grille1" is not compatible with "grille4" and "grille5".
The class are here to have to get the correspondant ID to hide.

```
<script>
$("li").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   alert(myClass); 
});
</script>
```

I want to find a way, for each classes I get from var myClass, to hide the correspondant ID.

On #grille1.click, #grille4 and #grille5 will hide.
On #grille2.click, #grille4 and #grille5 will hide.
...
On #grill4.click, #grille1 and #grille2 will hide.

I can't find a script wich the same goal... Or I don't use the good keywords.

I know i must use .each and array classes from myClass...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So for every `<li>` element you have, you want to hide the other `<li>` elements whose `id` properties match the class-names?

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/shc0qmju/#&togetherjs=MPe4J371bz)

```js
$('li').on('click',function(){
var classTerm=$(this).attr('class');
$.each(classTerm.split(' '),function(i,item){
if(item!='')
{
$('#'+item).hide();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-grids">
<li id="grille1" class="grille4 grille5 ">first</li>
<li id="grille2" class="grille4 grille5 ">second</li>
<li id="grille3" class="grille5 ">third</li>
<li id="grille4" class="grille1 grille2 ">fourth</li>
<li id="grille5" class="grille1 grille2 grille3 ">fifth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fantastic !

And, if the user click again on the first clicked li, could hidded ID show again ?

Comment: you need to reload or fire a event to get them show

Comment: for show check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/pzza5my6/#&togetherjs=n7qtIfazCr)

Answer (score 0):

On click get the classes then split them and hide.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   var ids=myClass.trim().split(" ");
   $.each(ids,function(index,value){
 $("#"+value).hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-grids">
<li id="grille1" class="grille4 grille5 ">1</li>
<li id="grille2" class="grille4 grille5 ">2</li>
<li id="grille3" class="grille5 ">3</li>
<li id="grille4" class="grille1 grille2 ">4</li>
<li id="grille5" class="grille1 grille2 grille3 ">5</li>
</ul>
```